# xarray - computation on one variable based on condition of anther variable

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-xarray

With Python 3.6.5 and xarray 0.12.1, I have created a Dataset named `ds_merge` with two variables named `v1` and `v2` merged together.

I need to do computation on `v1` based on values of `v2`.

```
print(ds_merge)

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 2, y: 3)
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) <U1 'a' 'b'
  * y        (y) <U1 'A' 'B' 'C'
Data variables:
    v1       (x, y) float64 0.8332 0.09855 1.477 0.6563 -0.1991 -0.9999
    v2       (x, y) bool True True True True False False
```

What I want to achieve is to multiply `v1` by 10 only in the circumstance of `v2` being `True`, such that `ds_merge` will be:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 2, y: 3)
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) <U1 'a' 'b'
  * y        (y) <U1 'A' 'B' 'C'
Data variables:
    v1       (x, y) float64 8.332 0.9855 14.77 6.563 -0.1991 -0.9999
    v2       (x, y) bool True True True True False False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like xarray does not support 2-dim boolean indexing. But numpy does, so you can just do:

```py
ds_merge['v1'].values[ds_merge['v2'].values] *= 10
```

Comment: Thanks @Ian. The Boolean or mask indexing is really powerful.