# How to add a constant to negative values in array

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

Given the xarray below, I would like to add 10 to all negative values (i.e, -5 becomes 5, -4 becomes 6 ... -1 becomes 9, all values remain unchanged).

```py
a = xr.DataArray(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)-5, dims=("x", "y"))
```

I tried:

- `a[a<0]=10+a[a<0]`, but it returns `2-dimensional boolean indexing is not supported`.
- Several attempts with `a.where`, but it seems that the `other` argument can only replace the mapped values with a constant rather than with indexed values.

I also considered using numpy as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56013101/xarray-computation-on-one-variable-based-on-condition-of-anther-variable), but my actual dataset is ~ 80 Gb and loaded with dask and using numpy crashes my Jupyter console.

Is there any way to achieve this using only `xarray`?

### Update

I updated the code using @SpaceBurger and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60720294/2-dimensional-boolean-indexing-in-dask). However my initial example was using a DataArray whereas my true problem is using a Dataset:

```py
a = xr.DataArray(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)-5, dims=("x", "y"))
a = a.to_dataset(name='variable')
```

Now, if I do this:

```py
a1 = a['variable']
a2 = 10+a1.copy()
a['variable'] = dask.array.where(a['variable'] < 0, a2, a1)
```

I get this error:

```
MissingDimensionsError: cannot set variable 'variable' with 2-dimensional data without explicit dimension names. Pass a tuple of (dims, data) instead.
```

Can anyone suggest a proper syntax?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60720294/2-dimensional-boolean-indexing-in-dask) help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xarray’s [`where`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.where.html) method is the way to go here - you can provide any *other* argument which can be broadcast against the *condition* argument and the original array:

```py
a['variable'] = a['variable'].where(
    a['variable'] >= 0,
    (a['variable'] + 10),
)
```

This will work fine with dask and will handle your coordinates seamlessly.

Note that if you do try this with a dataset, all of the variables in the dataset will be broadcast against the condition and other. so if you have some data vars that don't include all these dimensions they'll end up being repeated and weird. generally I recommend doing math/operations on DataArrays or variables as I have it in my answer.

Comment: Gosh - I swear I tried that! Thanks for the answer. Sorry @SpaceBurger, I have to accept this answer as it is pure xarray...

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is based on my meagre understanding of these libraries, and especially the [xarray.Dataset.update](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.update.html?highlight=Dataset.update) section of the xarray doc. This says the signature of `xarray.Dataset.update` parameters should be `mapping {var name: (tuple of dimension names, array-like)}`.

This means that datasets expect you to give them the name of the coordinates the data is attached to. And this makes some sense, as you should be able to see the name or the coordinates used in your dataset when printing the object (`print(a)`). Printing the dataset should give you the name of the coordinates generated with the call to `a.to_dataset`. Let us say they are named `coord_x` and `coord_y`. You should be able to set your data variable with

```py
a['variable'] = (('coord_x', 'coord_y'), dask.array.where(a['variable'] < 0, a2, a1))
```

Which should be equivalent to

```py
a.update('variable': (('coord_x', 'coord_y'), dask.array.where(a['variable'] < 0, a2, a1))
```

Or maybe the following that makes it easier to read but it doesn't use `dask` so it might not be as efficient.

```py
a.assign(variable=lambda x: x.variable+10 if x.variable<0 else x.variable)
```

So, to summarize you should be able to do the following :

```py
>>> a = xr.DataArray(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)-5, dims=("x", "y")) # 2D data with dims X and Y
>>> a = a.to_dataset(name='variable') # Should create a dataset with X and Y coordinates

>>> print(a) # Make sure X and Y are the correct names generated by the previous call
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:        (X: 2, Y: 2)
Coordinates:
  * X            (X) int64 10 20 ...
  * Y            (Y) int64 150 160 ...
Data variables:
  * variable     (X,Y) int64 1 2 3 4 5 ...

>>> a1 = a['variable']
>>> a2 = 10+a1.copy()
>>> a['variable'] = (('X', 'Y'), dask.array.where(a['variable'] < 0, a2, a1))
```

Comment: Thanks loads! And sorry for calling you SpaceBugger instead of SpaceBurger ^_^

Comment: xarray also has a `where` method which will handle coordinates and work natively with dask or numpy based arrays: `a['variable'] = xr.where(a['variable'] < 0, a2, a1)` or just `a['variable'] = a['variable'].where(a['variable'] >= 0, (a['variable'] + 10))`